# Почему идёт неверный подсчёт данных в таблице БД?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3, count

Встретился с проблемой что БД на SQLite неверно ведёт подсчёт кол-ва строк, хотя запросу соответствует одна строка. Пожалуйста, подскажите в чём проблема?

---

### Запрос SQLite

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LC WHERE BOOK = '"Капитанская дочка"' AND AUT = 'Александр Сергеевич Пушкин' AND (STAT = 'На руках' OR STAT = 'Просрочена')
```

---

### Скрин данных в БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас перепутаны значения в полях `AUT` и `BOOK`.